# Compile specific files only when NuGet package is referenced

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, csproj

In `.csproj` files one can specify that specific files should not be compiled when a defined condition is met. For example the following code would exclude (thus not compile) SomeFileA, B and C if the target framework is net35.

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net35' ">
    <Compile Remove="Some\Folder\SomeFileA.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Some\Folder\SomeFileB.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Some\Folder\SomeFileC.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

My question is if something like this can somehow also be achieved for if a specific NuGet package is referenced in a project referencing this project.

---

**Background:** I'm developing a library (further calling it **FW**) that I want to publish as a NuGet package in a private package source. All but one file (**X**) in **FW** work without references to any other NuGet package. This one file needs the NuGet package **ABC** to work. **FW** should later be referenced by various of my (and my coworkers) projects. But not all of these projects will need the functionality provided by file **X**. Therefore my idea was that I let the creator of a project (referencing **FW**) decide if he wants to use the functionality of file **X** by manually referencing NuGet package **ABC** or not. Depending on this (existing or missing) reference to **ABC** I want the file **X** to be compiled (existing) or not (missing).

I know, the bestestest way would propably be to create a separate project (**FW.X**) that references **FW** and **ABC** and create a separate NuGet package for it, so the project creator can decide to reference **FW** or **FW.X** but that's too much overhead for my use-case.

Comment: There's no way for you to do that, and I don't understand why you think 2 Nuget packages is too much overhead, seems like a fine use to me.

Comment: That's not much overhead. But... What about packaging the nuget as source files that get included and conditionally added based on custom props/targets also included, instead of packaging DLLs? You can hook into tons of places in MSBuild. This would have the downside that each project has their own version of the types defined (so no sharing directly between them) but that might be OK depending on your use case